# Is there way for getting passed time in solidity?

Tags: solidity, evm

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Try{

    uint public deployedTime;

    constructor(){

        deployedTime = block.timestamp;

    }
    
    function getPassedTime() public view returns(uint256){
        return block.timestamp - deployedTime;

    }
    
}
```

I tried to get passed time from contract's deployed time. For doing this i used `block.timestamp`' but it is the time where block is mined. This makes getPassedTime function not like 1,2,3 which is real passed time, but it only gives when block is mined.Is there any way for getting real passed time in solidity.

Comment: The only valid time is when the block is mined. Anything else is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

If **'getting real passed time'** means the seconds elapsed from the moment you click the deploy button to the moment you call the `getPassedTime()` function, then I don't think there is anyway to achieve this.

Any kind of transactions including the contract deployment made to the Ethereum depends hardly on the network congestion so the moment you click the deploy button isn't necessarily equal to the moment the deploy transaction is mined into a block.